# Attribute names changed in symbols after running distance tool

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I'm struggling to understand why names in one column of my attribute table are changed into symbols after performing the *distance to nearest hub (line to point)* tool in QGIS 3. My reference shapefile I perform the tool with has a series of GPS points, and a name (in French) for each point as shown below:

[image]

The encoding is set as UTF-8

Then, once the tool has finished running I have this in my attribute table:

The encoding is still set to UTF-8 but now where all the tonic accents are, I have those symbols appearing. Any insight on what I may be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Change the encoding to "system", then everything should look fine. I have no idea, why Qgis behaves like this, maybe someone can shed light.

Comment: @Erik, thanks, worked out great